# Swift: full frame of child view is not visible how to make child view scrollable when using XLPagerTabStrip?

Tags: swift

I have designed all desigen in storyboard and connected scroll view to containerView when i move to child view i am not able to see bottom component of child view and its not scrollable how can I fix this issue? please suggest
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaYST.png)

Comment: Your view controller is probably adjusting scroll view insets. Go to the project's storyboard and select the view controller where you are adding the table, and uncheck the option Adjust Scroll View Insets

Comment: i did it but the same problem not scrollable

Comment: Did the comment below solve your problem.?

Comment: i did it but not worked

Answer (score -1):

Add this in your code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None
        self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = false
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

    }
```

Comment: i did it but the same problem not scrollable

Comment: You are using a table view and last cell in not completely seen am i right.?

Comment: No im not using table view this is simple form for sign up

Comment: Can you share your code.? how have you set up your scroll view.

Comment: well i guess there is a problem with you constraints.Somewhere there is a static height for a view in a view controller.please check that once..

Comment: im using XLPagerTabStrip open source pod I have designed all desigen in storyboard and connected scroll view to containerView like this link https://medium.com/michaeladeyeri/how-to-implement-android-like-tab-layouts-in-ios-using-swift-3-578516c3aa9 and all fine but child view i am not able to see bottom component of child view and its not scrollable

Comment: This issue is also reported to developers but is not answered.So i suggest you to use a table view in child view controller instead of stucking into this problem.